# Is the projection of a smooth submanifold a submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Given $S\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ a submanifold, i.e. for all $x\in S$ there exists an open $A\ni x$, open $B\ni 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and smooth diffeomorphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ such that $f(A\cap S)=(\mathbb{R}^d\times\{0\})\cap B$ for $d$  is the dimension of $S$, such that $(x_1,...,x_n,,x_{n+1}),(x_1,...,x_n,x_{n+1}')\in S\Rightarrow x_{n+1}=x_{n+1}'$, is the projection of $S$ onto the first $n$ coordinates also a submanifold?

Intuition tells me yes with the last condition used to prevent self-intersections, but I can't seem to be able to construct the diffeomorphism required, mostly because I can't explicitly write $x_{n+1}$ smoothly in terms of the other coordinates when on $S$. This seems like an elementary question too yet the literature says very little about projecting submanifolds.

Comment: Yes, it's an injectivity condition that excludes the trivial counter-examples.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Edited now.

Comment: In light of the answers below, I'd still be interested in seeing a counterexample to this (with the injectivity condition) if we additionally (i) assume $S$ is compact (ii) allow the projection to be a $C^0$ manifold and not get too fussed about it being smoothness that breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Imagine a 2D sheet of paper floating perpendicularly above the $x$-axis of the plane and centered at the origin.  Twist the lower end 90 degrees clockwise parallel to the $y$-axis, and the upper end 90 degrees counterclockwise parallel to the $y$-axis, leaving the vertical line above the origin fixed.  The projection down of this looks something like two triangles joined at one vertex (at the origin).

**Edit due to injectivity condition:** Still don't think it suffices.  Imagine an open line segment in $\mathbb{R}^3$ bent into something that projects onto the $(x,y)$-plane as a figure-eight, but where the cross-point in the projection onto the $(x,y)$-plane is below the 'holes' at the open endpoints, and one point on the interior of the line segment (i.e. the curve is arranged so the endpoint holes and this interior point all differ only in the $z$-coordinate, and the rest of the open line segment forms the remainder of the figure-eight).

Comment: It's my fault for not writing the condition down correctly the first time, but I stipulate a kind of injectivity condition so that you can't have more than one point in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ project down onto the same point in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @PepeSilvia Oh ok! I've tried to update my response accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple counterexample. Let $S\subset\mathbb R^3$ be the curve parametrized by $\gamma(t) = (t^3, t^2, t)$.  Its projection onto the $(x,y)$-plane is the cusp curve defined by $y^3 = x^2$, which is not a smooth submanifold. The projection is injective because $t_1^3 = t_2^3$ implies $t_1=t_2$.

Comment: Is that a smooth manifold? I think it may have a cusp at 0 even in 3D.

Comment: @PepeSilvia: Yes, it's definitely a smooth submanifold. Since $\gamma'(t)$ is never zero, $\gamma$ is an injective immersion of $\mathbb R$. And it's is a homeomorphism onto its image because the restriction to $S$ of the map $(x,y,z)\mapsto z$ is a continuous inverse for it. Therefore $S$ is the image of a smooth embedding, hence it's an embedded smooth submanifold.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is most definitely no. Think of a sheet of paper twisting in $3$-space. The sheet is a $2$-manifold, and its projection will mostly also be a $2$-manifold (locally), but for some angles it will be reduced to a line/point.

EDIT: Added an image of what the projection typically looks like. The projection is the shaded cone.

[image]

Comment: a line is a smooth submanifold as well...(a point, too)

Comment: Doesn't that violate the last condition though?

Comment: @PepeSilvia no. Take the graph of $x^{1/3}$ (possible times $\mathbb R$ to get something two dimensional in three space)

Comment: @Thomas The projection is not just a line or a point. It should generally look like a flat cone in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and the problem point is obviously the one between each half of the cone.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Right. But if you provide a counter example it's more convincing if it actually _is_ a counterexample to the claim. What you have written is not.

Comment: But it is a counter example. It's clear from your comment you did not understand it.

Comment: I've added an image of what a typical projection in my example looks like.

Comment: At this problem point, call it $(x_0,y_0)$, you have an infinite number of points of the form $(x_0,y_0,z)$, violating the condition I stated.

Comment: "It's clear from your comment that you did not understand it" - I don't think this is clear from my comment, but it may still be true.

Comment: Alright, I had not understood your injectivity condition at first; it does exclude this kind of counter-example. Might try to think of something else.